# how to acces getter from module vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

i have create module in vuex, but how to access getters in computed ?
here is product template

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in productAll" :key="item._id">
            <p>hello word</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
    computed:{
        productAll(){
            return this.$store.getters.productAll
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

and this is my store

```
const productModule = {
  state: () => ({
    product: [

    ]
  }),
  getters:{
    productAll(context){
      return [
        "123","456"
      ]
      // return state.product.data
    }
  },
}

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    productModule
  },
}
```

i only return array 123 345 in "store.getters.productAll", if i put array 123 345 in computed it is working, will show hello word 2 times, but why when i put in store module it is not working ?

Comment: Your code seems fine as it is. Are you sure you are importing your store correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike actions, getters don't receive a `context` object.  They receive 4 arguments:

```
(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters)
```

- `state`:  Current module state
- `getters`:  Current module getters
- `rootState`:  Root module state (and module-to-module access)
- `rootGetters`: Root module getters (and module-to-module access)

So create your getter this way:

```js
getters: {
  productAll(state) {
    return state.product.data
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Need some clarification..

1. state: current module state
2. getters: we can access current module getters.
3. rootState: we can access other module's state.
4. rootGetters: we can access other module's getters.

Please corrrect me, If I am wrong here..

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Hi, yes you got it. I'll update my answer to show more details.

Comment: still not working, i event not access stage, i only return array [123,345] in the store.getter but not showing hello word 2 times, this getters is under productModule

Comment: Probably because `product` is an array not an object, so `product.data` makes no sense.